# Не работает return в асинхронной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, асинхронность, print, return

У меня есть асинхронная функция с асинхронным HTTP запросом:

```
    async def posts(self, thread_id):
        async with ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.post(url = url,
                                headers = self.headers
                                ) as resp:
                return resp
```

Но при её вызове она ничего не возращает, хотя, если `return resp` заменить на `print(resp)`, то всё выводится.

Comment: А как вызываете? С await?

Comment: пробовал с await `await return resp`, но выдавало ошибку `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Тогда нужен какой-то менеджер вроде asyncio. Я в питоне не очень с асинхронностью умею, надо читать что-то

Answer (score 4):

Можно вызывать через asyncio: `resp = asyncio.run( posts(thread_id) )`

```
import asyncio

async def x():
    return 0

print( x() ) # <coroutine object x at 0x000001B...>
             # Синхронный вызов не дает ожидаемый результат

print( asyncio.run(x()) ) # 0
```

Comment: а если мне нужно вызывать через asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())?

Comment: @ZeN `C://Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Lib/asyncio/runners.py` - здесь посмотрел исходный код run(), а он внутри вызывает тот же `run_until_complete`. Получается одно и то же, а здесь - https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html предлагают использовать 'высокоуровневую' `run()`

Comment: попробовал вызвать через run(), выдало ошибку RuntimeError: Event loop is closed