# Как получить строку из асинхронной функции при помощи return

Tags: python, python-3.x, asyncio

Пытаюсь разобраться в асинхронности, вся функция работает, но выводит

`({<Task finished name='Task-3' coro=<call_url() done, defined at Путь до папки\test.py:7> result='irinabsm1@yandex.ru'>, <Task finished name='Task-2' coro=<call_url() done, defined at Путь до папки\test.py:7> result='irinabsm1@yandex.ru'>}, set()`

Как сделать более чистый вывод и получить только результуат? Сразу скажу, что [похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1268825/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-return-%D0%B2-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) мне не помог.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = ['https://e-ecolog.ru/entity/2360009926','https://e-ecolog.ru/entity/2360009926']

async def call_url(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:

            data = await response.text()
            soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
            mail = soup.find(itemprop="email")


    return mail.string

futures = [call_url(url) for url in urls]

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(futures))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде так можно результаты получить:

```
results = [task.result() for task in futures]
```

Только наверное `wait` нужно на `gather` поменять, чтобы сделать ожидание всем задачам. Только звёздочку не забудьте тут:

```
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*futures))
```

И вызовы тоже поменять, спасибо andreymal:

```
futures = [loop.create_task(call_url(url)) for url in urls]
```

Ну, я пока в `asyncio` и сам ещё не совсем разбираюсь.

Comment: Выдает ошибку sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'call_url' was never awaited

Comment: Добавил к ответу

Comment: Теперь выдает ошибку AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'result'

Comment: @Bubunduc `futures = [loop.create_task(call_url(url)) for url in urls]`

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за помошь

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо за ответ

Comment: Кстати, если уж вызывать `asyncio.gather`, то он сам вернёт готовый список результатов и вызывать `task.result()` уже нет необходимости

Comment: @andreymal Напишите свой ответ с нормальным кодом, а то получается я своим ответом только дезинформирую тех, кто будет читать )

Comment: Ах да, по хорошему надо бы ещё отменять все оставшиеся в фоне task'и и вызывать shutdown_asyncgens... @Bubunduc есть какая-то причина, по которой вы не использовали функцию `asyncio.run`, или вы просто не в курсе её существования?

Comment: Может я чего не так сделал не так, но она у меня не работает